# Pipe less to Emacs

Tags: emacs

When viewing piped output to Less, sometimes I'd like to be able to view it in Emacs in order to get syntax highlighting and use emacs commands for searching, marking, copying, etc.

I see that Less has a `v` command that can be used to open the currently viewed file in `$EDITOR`.  Unfortunately this doesn't work when viewing piped input.

Also, I don't know how to get Emacs to display stdin as a read-only document.

So, is it possible to set up Less with something like `v` but that pumps the current buffer into Emacs as a read-only file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you scroll down in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuClient, you'll come to a section titled "Piping data to an Emacs buffer" which may be relevant. <s>Or you can [hack up a solution involving emacsclient and temporary files](http://www.shellarchive.co.uk/content/emacs_tips.html#have-emacsclient-accept-stuff-from-stdin).</s> (link dead).

I found another variant while looking for a duplicate of the dead link: [Piping to an emacs buffer with emacsclient](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2011/03/03/piping-to-an-emacs-buffer-with-emacsclient) which points at [code stored on github](https://gist.github.com/857999).

Comment: http://www.shellarchive.co.uk/content/emacs_tips.html#have-emacsclient-accept-stuff-from-stdin
above link does not work. Can you please update the link.

Comment: @CantGetANick: I'd love to, but I don't have an alternative version. Gah!

Answer (score 5):

I've formalized the solution here: [github e-sink](https://github.com/lewang/e-sink)

Comment: Thanks +1 ... This is **much** faster (real time) than `emacs-pipe.pl` in the other answer 
Using `cat file`, where *file* contains the output of `printf '%s\n' {0000001..1000000} >file`.....  
`emacs-pipe.pl` --> time: r/u/s:  `2m23.487s` `0m8.461s` `0m4.976s` ..... whereas, this one:
`e-sink.pl` --> time: r/u/s:  `0m14.796s` `0m11.289s` `m3.492s` .....   
But when used with `--cmd`, I get an error: *Your vendor has not defined POSIX macro ARG_MAX, used at /home/axiom/bin/e-sink.pl line 182* .. Is there a simple fix for this? (my perl knowledge is rather scant)

Comment: The --cmd implementation was the original slow implementation.  I've fixed the error you encountered, but stick with the new one.  Cheers.